# Which (Java) code, library, or algorithm is best at providing similarities between bit patterns?

Tags: java

I am after code, a library routine, or an algorithm that scores how close two different bit or boolean patterns are. Naturally if they are equal then the score should be 1, while if one is all true and the other all false then the score should 0.

**Bit pattern example**

The bit patterns that i will be testing are many times never actually equal or the same but sometimes they are very similar.

```
0001 1111 0000
0000 1111 1100
0000 1110 0000
1110 0000 1111
```

In the above examples 1 & 2 or 1 & 3 are pretty close if i was to score them perhaps the difference would be something like 96 and 95%. On the other hand 1&4 would definitely be a much lower score maybe 25%.

Note that bit patterns may be of different lengths but scoring should still be possible.

```
001100
000011110000
```

The above two patterns would be considered identical.

```
001100
00110000
```

The above two patterns would be considered close but not identical, because once "scaled" #2 is different from #1.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific than that. Are these patterns similar? `10101010` `01010101`? They don't have a single bit in common, but they are similar (at least to me)

Comment: @Kaj your right the patterns you show are pretty close, my wish component would score them pretty high 95+.

Answer (score 4):

If the bit patterns are all the same length, just use the exclusive-or (`^`) operator and count how many zeroes remain.

(`xor` produces a zero if the two corresponding bits are the same, and a one otherwise).

If they're of different lengths, treat the bit pattern as if it were a string and use something like the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: Xor isnt very smart it has no concept of distance. 1000 vs 0100 is closer than 1000 vs 0001 yet both have bit difference of 1 bit.

Comment: so convert to strings and use Levenshtein, as per my answer.  It counts the minimum number of edits necessary to change the string from one to the other.

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing around with fast ways to count the number of matching bits of the bit-wise `XOR` comparison. Here's what I think is the fastest way:

```
int num1, num2; // some bit patterns
int diff = num1 ^ num2;
int score;
for (score = 0; diff > 0; diff >>>= 1)
    score += diff & 1;
```

A score of zero means exact match (assuming results of the same length).

Comment: `diff >>= 1` will loop infinitely when the high bit is set since `>>` is sign-extending.  You need `diff >>>= 1` or don't iterate over all bits by doing `diff = diff & (diff - 1)` or just use `Integer.bitCount(...)`

Comment: Hi @B look my example your detection is a little simplistic and only works for exact matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int bitwiseEditDistance(int a, int b) {
  return Integer.bitCount(a ^ b);
}
```

[`Integer.bitCount`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount%28int%29) is an obscure little bit of the core libraries.

> Returns the number of one-bits in the two's complement binary representation of the specified `int` value. This function is sometimes referred to as the population count.

Comment: Too simplistic for my needs, refer to my edits for an example.

Comment: @mP, until you define the problem I can't help you.  I can point you at `java.util.BitSet`.  It's `nextSetBit` and `nextClearBit` methods should make it very easy to experiment with runs of bits.